# how to make the program find an image with pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

In the code below as you can see i'm trying to find an image in the screen with a .png(that i didn't add because i don't think it's the problem) but it doesn't find anything

```
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep

class Clicker:
    def __init__(self, target_png, speed):
        self.target_png = target_png
        self.speed = speed
        pt.FAILSAFE = True

    def nav_to_image(self):
        try:
            position = pt.locateOnScreen(self.target_png, confidence=.8)
            pt.moveTo(position[0] + 15, position[1] + 15, duration=self.speed)
            pt.doubleClick()

        except:
            print('No img found')
            return 0

if __name__=='__main__':
    sleep(1)
    clicker = Clicker('accetta.png', speed=.001)

    end = 0
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        if clicker.nav_to_image() == 00:
            end += 1

        if end > 5:
            break
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you confidence is set to 80%. It's a little tricky when you're not looking for the exact match. Have you tested the code with an image that doesn't require confidence to work?

Sometimes there is a difference in the hue. Try locateOnScreen(image, grayscale=False) and see if that makes a difference.

It would help if you included both the image you're trying to find and a copy of the screenshot in order to reproduce the error.